# сохранить выделенную область OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Вот я сделал, чтобы распознавалось ухо в реальном времени.Оно выделяется в синию рамку.Как сделать, чтобы как только оно нашло ухо, программа сохранила фото уха в отдельный файл и закрылась?

```
import cv2


ear_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ear = ear_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in ear:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==ord('q'):
        break

#cv2.imwrite('ear.jpg',img)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоритически на картинке может быть много ушей, поэтому в общем случае после выполнения:

```
ear = ear_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

в переменной `ear` будут хранится координаты и размеры `bounding boxes` для всех найденных ушей.

Если вас интересует только первое найденное ухо, то можно сделать так (код я не тестировал):

```
import cv2

def find_first_ear(cap):
    ear_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml')

    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        for (x, y, w, h) in ear_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5):
            # возвращаем часть картинки, ограниченную первой найденной рамкой
            return img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key==ord('q'):
            break
    return None

res_path = r'c:/temp/ear.jpg'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.imwrite(res_path, find_first_ear(cap))
```

PS изображения в OpenCV представляют из себя 3D Numpy матрицы, где первые два измерения это координаты пикселя `Y` и `X` на экране, а третье измерение - это кортеж интенсивности цветовых каналов - **RGB** (**R**ed **G**reen **B**lue) или **BGR** (**B**lue **G**reen **R**ed), поэтому для обрезки изображения можно воспользоваться Numpy срезами (`slicing`) по первым двум измерениям (координатам).

Comment: у меня будет 1 человек на фото,но сейчас попробую ваш вариант

Comment: спасибо, заработало